# Linq to Sql Deferred Loading

Tags: linq, lazy-loading

If you do not plan to use lazy loading, should deferred loading be explicity set to false within a "using" block? It seems to me that child objects are being loaded by dataContext within the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want any lazy loading at all you can turn it off by modifying the properties on the DBML. This will then cause the DataContext to be generated with it turned off by default

Comment: in the dbml designer table properties? it shows false by default for some reason, but still works.